# Invalid UTF-8 bytes

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences):

> Not all sequences of bytes are valid UTF-8. A UTF-8 decoder should be
> prepared for:
>
> ```
> 1. the red invalid bytes in the above table
> 2. an unexpected continuation byte
> 3. a start byte not followed by enough continuation bytes
> 4. an Overlong Encoding as described above
> 5. A 4-byte sequence (starting with 0xF4) that decodes to a value greater than U+10FFFF
> ```

As per the Codepage layout, `0xC0` and `0xC1` are invalid and must never appear in a valid UTF-8 sequence. Here is what I have for CodePoints `0xC0` and `0xC1`:

```
Byte 2   Byte 1      Num   Char
11000011 10000000    192   À
11000011 10000001    193   Á
```

There are characters corresponding to these byte sequences, while there should not be. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You're confusing code points and code units.

Comment: The two lines contain {xc3+x80} -> xc0 -> 192 and {xc3+x81} -> xc1 ->193 (and you appear to have byte2 and byte1 swapped)

Comment: @wildplasser, you can guess from the sequence of bits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're just confusing terms:

The **codepoint** U+00C0 is the character "À", U+00C1 is "Á".
Encoded in UTF-8 they're the **byte sequence** `C3 80` and `C3 81` respectively.

The **bytes** `C0` and `C1` should never appear in the UTF-8 encoding.

*Codepoints* denote characters independently of bytes. *Bytes* are bytes.